# Why Spring Boot Cloud Config Server properties not picked from GIT

Tags: spring-boot, configuration-files

I have the following issue. Just with the basic Spring Boot Config Server, I would like to read property file from my Github (i tried also Gitlab). **Everything works localy**, the property file is nicely loaded from Github, but after deploying application **on any other environment, for example on Heroku or on dedicated Linux** server, the property file is **not loaded**. I am checking http://localhost:8101/employee/service1 
Loading the property file from local files (classpath:config/local) works very well both locally and on other environments. What I am doing wrong? I have created simple project on Github (https://github.com/troger19/config-server), if anybody can check. Also app is deployed on Heroku: https://protected-savannah-48323.herokuapp.com/employee/service1

The application.yml looks like this

```
server:
   port: 8101
 spring:
  application:
   name: config-server
cloud:
  config:
    server:
     git:
       uri: https://github.com/troger19/config-server
       search-paths: src\main\resources\config\dev
```

And the employee-service1.yml is in resources/config/dev

I havent find anything in the logs so far. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: In search path can you use forward slash when you deploy this might be issue as working on your local window machine

Comment: Seems like that was the problem, changing the slashes seems working on Heroku environment, so I guess it would work also on Red Hat Linus machines on my real project.. thanks you man, you really help me.. how can I mark your comment as a correct answer?

Comment: great, I have posted my answer. Answer has an option to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change use `"/"` for linux environment as `"\"` will only work on window environment.

Please change your search-paths: `src\main\resources\config\dev` to  `/src/main/resources/configdev`

Good idea to use different-2 profile in `yml` file for different environment so such can be avoided.

Comment: Thanks kj007.. the other thing, that was missing was the leading / ath the beginning